# amp build and deploy to personal server

Tags: build, components, amp-html

Is it possible to build an [amp](https://amp.dev/) custom component locally and deploy to my own server?

I tried `gulp build` and it generates some files in the `dist` folder but when I try to use that generated component file in a amp page, the scripts url changes on runtime to `https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-my-widget-0.1.js` which does not exist!!!

Comment: Why not use `amp-script` instead?

Comment: @StefanyNewman tried it, too many restrictions, made it impossible for my needs, my component is a chat widget sample: http://farhadadeli.ir/idemandu/chat-qa.html

Comment: @JayGray I Don't what to rewrite the widget from scratch and I don't want to maintain to different versions  , I want to be able to use what I have now with small changes that won't break the current system